# How to loop a jQuery div animation?

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate

I’m trying to implement a jQuery function with an infinite loop to animate a div. I can’t figure out how to do it. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divers').animate({
        'margin-top': '90px'
    }, 6000).animate({
        'margin-top': '40px'
    }, 6000);
});
```

Comment: Done! Thank you everybody for your time and patience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

put the code that does the full animation into a function, then pass that function as the callback param to the last animation.  Something like...

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    function animateDivers() {
        $('#divers').animate(
            {'margin-top':'90px'}
            ,6000
        )
        .animate(
            {'margin-top':'40px'}
            ,6000
            ,animateDivers //callback the function, to restart animation cycle
        ); 
    }

    animateDivers(); //call, to start the animation
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this. But can you please tell me what if i want to move image that is put using canvas?

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function ani() {
        $('#divers').animate({
               'margin-top':'90px'
            },6000).animate({
               'margin-top':'40px'
           },6000, ani); //call the function again in the callback
        }); 
    }); 
    ani();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `.animate()` callback to 'recall' your function:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ihapah/1/edit)*

```
$(function() {
  
  
  function loop(){
   $('#divers')
     .animate({marginTop:90},6000)
     .animate({marginTop:40},6000, loop); // callback
  }
  
  loop(); // call this wherever you want


});
```

Comment: It's working perfect!! thanks for take your time and put a great demo. Must apreciated

Answer (score 2):

Using setInterval is the way to go. Too much recursion will just get you "Stack Overflow" :-)
"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Answer (score 1):

The `animate()` function has an option to take a function to call when the animation ends. You could just do the same call, and voila.

Comment: Now i get it, i just needed to see the code to figure out how. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the  set interval function specifying which method to call at what interval

```
$(function () { setInterval(fnName, 6000); });
```